# Broken: Elif in For loop with increment counter

Tags: bash, for-loop, counter, conditional-statements

I wrote a short script to generate a formatted string for syllable synthesis in macintalk.  I would like to insert a silence every 20 syllables so I wrote a for loop with a counter stored in a tempfile and a nested elif statement that is supposed to add a silence command every time the counter reaches 20.  The counter then resets after it reaches 20.

For some reason I can't divine, the elif is only accessed on the first time the conditional is found true.  In other words: The first time the counter reaches 20 it inserts the silence command, resets and continues the loop.  The second time the counter reaches 20, the elif is not accessed and continues to grow until $k reaches it's maximum value.

Does anyone have any clue why this code won't work?

EDIT ** here is a slightly longer excerpt as per popular request =)

Here are the links to the files if you would like to try to reproduce:
[syllables_phncode.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7vbpw34fquwrih/syllables_phncode.txt?dl=0)
[cbsyllindx.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1klcr2nhkxw24vz/cbsyllindx.txt?dl=0)

```
# Load Syllables
echo ''
echo 'Opening Syllable Transcription for Victoria'
echo ''
syllfile=./syllables_phncode.txt
syllables=$(cat $syllfile)
syllarray=()
counter=0;
# Create Indexed Array of Phonological Code for Syllables
for k in $syllables
do
    echo $counter
    echo $k
    syllarray[counter]=$k
    counter=$(($counter + 1));
done
# Load syllable index for stimulus stream
indxfile=./cbsyllindx.txt
indx=$(cat $indxfile)
stream=''
tempfile=count.tmp
echo 0 > $tempfile
echo '====================================================================================='
echo 'Counter Balanced Stimulus Order (Indexed by Syllables in Alphabetical Order)'
echo '====================================================================================='
echo $indx
echo '====================================================================================='
echo ''
echo 'Creating counterbalanced stimulus stream string with proper Macintalk formatting'
echo ''
for k in $indx
do
    counter=$[$(cat $tempfile) + 1]
    echo $counter > $tempfile
    if [ $k -eq 0 ]; then
        stream=$stream'@_'${syllarray[k]}
    elif [ $counter -eq 20 ]; then
    echo Adding Silence after syllable: ${syllarray[k]}
        stream=$stream'_'${syllarray[k]}'[[ slnc 20 ]]'
        echo 0 > $tempfile
    else
        stream=$stream'_'${syllarray[k]}
    fi
done
unlink $tempfile
echo '------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'Printing Stream to Screen'
echo '------------------------------------------------------'
echo $stream
```

Here is the string that is created by this script:

> _tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW[*[slnc20]]*_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW@_bIY_kUW_tIY_pIY_gOW_lAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_bUW_dOW_pAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_bUW_dOW_pAE_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_pIY_gOW_lAE_bUW_dOW_pAE

Comment: Any reason you don't just keep the counter in memory and modify it there, rather than writing and reading it from a temporary file every iteration of the loop?

Comment: I tried it that way at first and I get the same result.  I was reading on stack exchange that having a tempfile is useful if there is a subshell invoked, so I tried that out of desperation.

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious, but I couldn't see how to get the output you got.  I assume the output is in the variable *stream*.  What values did you use for *indx* and *syllarray*?

Comment: thanks for asking David, yup *stream* is the output that is created by concatenating the syllables from *syllarray* in the order specified by *indx* --

*syllarray* is read from a text file with the following strings:  bIY
bUW
dAE
dOW
gOW
kUW
lAE
pAE
pIY
rOW
tIY
tUW; 

*indx* is read from a file of 298 numbers that indicate which of the syllables are to be concatenated next into stream, this gives me the 298 syllables in the order you see in the above post

Comment: sure! I was trying to keep the post as short as possible,  but I can add all that ^_^

Comment: Whoops, I deleted my earlier comment.  It was something like this:  Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller set of inputs?  For extra points, edit your question to put code to create the inputs at the top, and add *echo "$stream"* at the bottom.

Comment: I was hoping we could reduce the overall size, mostly by getting the string created to be smaller.  If you can't make it shorter overall, please don't bother.  Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84965/discussion-between-david-vincent-and-seldamat).

Comment: update:  i've tried to make the string shorter and it seemed to work properly, however it doesn't scale when the string gets longer
-----
i also tried changing it from inserting a silence command from every 20 syllables to every single syllable (by changing -eq 20 to -eq 1)  and I get silences printed only for the first six iterations :-S

Comment: here is the truncated output from from changing 20 to 1:  _tUW[[ slnc 20 ]]_dAE[[ slnc 20 ]]_rOW[[ slnc 20 ]]_pIY[[ slnc 20 ]]_gOW[[ slnc 20 ]]_lAE[[ slnc 20 ]]@_bIY_kUW_tIY_tUW_dAE_rOW_

Comment: Can you shorten cbsyllindx.txt such that the output is as short as possible, but still shows the problem?  (Sorry I didn't get here sooner, and thanks for the work you've done in the last couple of days.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you hit the `$k -eq 0` check right when `$counter` equals `20` but you increment counter anyway and then once you've passed `20` you can never hit it again.

You can see this by adding `set -x` to the top of your script and running it and looking at the output.

You don't want if/else for unrelated checks it has this problem.

You probably want something more like this as the body of your loop.

```
if [ $k -eq 0 ]; then
    stream=${stream}@
fi
stream=${stream}_${syllarray[k]}
if [ $counter -eq 20 ]; then
    stream=$stream'[[ slnc 20 ]]'
fi
```

Which keeps the concerns separate.

You also don't (as indicated in the comments) need the tempfile here at all. (You don't have any sub-shells other than the ones that deal with reading your files which don't count.)

You can also avoid the `$(cat file)` subshells by using `$(< file)` instead.

You should also use `$((...))` instead of `$[...]` consistently.

Comment: Additionally, when using `((..))`, you do not include the `$` before the variable name inside the double-parens. e.g. (`counter=$(($counter + 1));` should be `counter=$((counter + 1))` or simply `((counter++))`. **Note:** there is no need for a line continuation (e.g. `;`) following the closing `))`.

Comment: I tried this solution and got the weirdest output, I also noticed earlier that if I changed the condition from 20 to 15 or some other number then it would insert silences after the first time but not every single time that condition was true.. I think my computer is schizophrenic :-S

Comment: Any time you have `$k -eq 0` be true you have a chance of skipping the associated `$counter -eq X` check. As soon as you skip that once your counter loop fails. So for any given `X` if you *ever* hit `$k -eq 0` on a multiple of that it will fail at exactly that point. What "weirdest" output did the fix get you?